# I don't understand how to fix dockle errors

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I built the image with `docker build -t nginx:stable .`
Here is Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:stable
USER root
WORKDIR /home/

COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY ./start.sh /home/

RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y gcc spawn-fcgi libfcgi-dev; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*; \
    chmod u-s /bin/su; \
    chmod u-s /usr/bin/newgrp; \
    chmod u-s /usr/bin/passwd; \
    chmod u-s /usr/bin/gpasswd; \
    chmod u-s /bin/umount; \
    chmod u-s /usr/bin/chfn; \
    chmod u-s /usr/bin/chsh; \
    chmod u-s /bin/mount; \
    chmod g-s /usr/bin/expiry; \
    chmod g-s /usr/bin/chage; \
    chmod g-s /usr/bin/wall; \
    chmod g-s /sbin/unix_chkpwd; \
    chown -R nginx:nginx /etc/nginx/nginx.conf; \
    chown -R nginx:nginx /home/; \
    chown -R nginx:nginx /var/cache/nginx; \
    touch /var/run/nginx.pid; \
    chown nginx:nginx /var/run/nginx.pid

USER nginx

HEALTHCHECK --interval=5m --timeout=3s \
 CMD curl -f http://localhost/ || exit 1

CMD ["sh", "./start.sh"]
```

Then I run the check with `dockle -ak NGINX_GPGKEY -i CIS-DI-0010 -t 5m nginx:stable`

Here is output:

```
WARN    - CIS-DI-0001: Create a user for the container
    * Last user should not be root
INFO    - CIS-DI-0006: Add HEALTHCHECK instruction to the container image
    * not found HEALTHCHECK statement
INFO    - CIS-DI-0008: Confirm safety of setuid/setgid files
    * setuid file: urwxr-xr-x usr/bin/passwd
    * setgid file: grwxr-xr-x usr/bin/chage
    * setuid file: urwxr-xr-x usr/bin/newgrp
    * setuid file: urwxr-xr-x usr/bin/chsh
    * setuid file: urwxr-xr-x bin/umount
    * setuid file: urwxr-xr-x usr/bin/chfn
    * setgid file: grwxr-xr-x sbin/unix_chkpwd
    * setuid file: urwxr-xr-x bin/mount
    * setgid file: grwxr-xr-x usr/bin/expiry
    * setgid file: grwxr-xr-x usr/bin/wall
    * setuid file: urwxr-xr-x usr/bin/gpasswd
    * setuid file: urwxr-xr-x bin/su
```

Не понимаю, почему эти ошибки остались. Вроде и пользователя изменил, и разрешения дал, и HEALTHCHECK на месте. Подскажите, что не так?

I don't understand why these errors persist. User changed, permissions given, HEALTHCHECK is in place. Where am I wrong?

I tried to delete `USER root`, rearranged the user addition back and forth in different ways. With HEALTHCHECK and permissions I don't know what else to do. Also tried to do `docker build -t img:new .`, but then i have
`FATAL  unable to initialize a image struct: failed to initialize source: reading manifest new in docker.io/library/img: requested access to the resource is denied`

Comment: With `docker build -t nginx:stable .` you might have overriden your local copy of the `nginx:stable` image. Maybe delete the image `nginx:stable` first, then try to build the image again using the `docker build` command with your own image name.

Comment: iItried `docker build` with my own image after I deleted all I had with `docker system prune -a`. But the error remains :(